# Create custom page to give permissions to a user for workspace using C# in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, permissions

We use Sharepoint 2010 as a intranet solution in our company.We have 1 web application and more than 5 site collections.Each site collection has different sites and each site has Workspace Site template.

I want to create a custom web page which contains each Workspace name as a column and Read/Write permission levels as a row in a datagrid.
So the admin can easily give permissions to a user for each of the workspace.
I mean the datagrid as follows;

```
               Workspace1     Workspace2     WOrkspace3
```

Read

Write

FullControl

I just want to learn that is my scenario possible?If it possible,where should I start from?

Comment: That sounds like a wonderful tool.  Let me know how development of it goes for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find a ready made solution for this. [Access Checker Webpart](http://accesschecker.codeplex.com/) for MOSS 2007 is a similar webpart which shows access details for a particular site collection (and subsites, lists etc). I would suggest downloading the code and modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Shoban.Actually I am not looking for a ready made solution.I want to develop it by using C#.I just want to learn that is my scenario possible?If it possible,where should I start from?

Comment: By downloading the above webpart :) .. its open source. Read the code and you will get some ideas. I wil check for other links.